# Propel - fetchArray or toArray

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, propel

In Doctrine i can use function fetchArray() instead of execute or toArray(). I can't founded equivalent these function for Propel. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really need array you can always use old Peer API

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
/* ...setup your criteria... */
$pdoStatement = AuthorPeer::doSelectStmt($criteria);
$array = $pdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `toArray()` just after `->find()`.

Either at once:

```
$authors = AuthorQuery::create()
  ->limit(5)
  ->find()
  ->toArray();
foreach ($authors as $author) {
  print_r($author);
}
```

Or in a loop:

```
$authors = AuthorQuery::create()
  ->limit(5)
  ->find()
foreach ($authors as $author) {
  print_r($author->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a propel result set like you can with an array

```
$authors = AuthorQuery::create()
  ->limit(5)
  ->find();
foreach ($authors as $author) {
  echo $authors->getFirstName();
}
```

http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#collections_and_ondemand_hydration